# Write a function in R that removes text that contains certain characters in column?

Tags: r, regex, twitter, gsub

I have a column that contains text from Twitter that are both original posts and responses/replies to accounts.

Example of df (2 rows out of 2 million):

```
ID |              Tweet                                
1    @mcr_chick i wanna sleep.lol.
2    Someone burned a hole.
```

I would like to remove all the tweets that have '@' and the respective name to is attached to the '@' symbol. As you can see - some tweets do not have the @name in the tweet - so I would need to somehow group by only IDs that contain '@' or something.

Desired output:

```
ID |              Tweet                   | Original_Tweet        | Reply_Tweet             
1    @mcr_chick i wanna sleep.lol.          NA                      i wanna sleep.lol.
2    Someone burned a hole.                 Someone burned a hole.
```

I am playing around with sub command to remove '@' from text and then delete first word in tweet but I still need to group by those that contain '@'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `str_extract` to extract the 'Tweet' that doesn't have the '@' characters from the start (`^`) of the string (thus the first row becomes NA because there is a `@` at the start) to create the 'Original_Tweet' and use `case_when` to create the 'Reply_tweet' column by removing the substring that starts with "@" followed by characters that are not a space along with any space (`\\s+`) (By default the `TRUE` in `case_when` returns NA)

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>% 
    mutate(Original_Tweet = str_extract(Tweet, "^[^@]+"), 
     Reply_tweet = case_when(str_detect(Tweet, "@") ~ 
           str_remove(Tweet, "^@[^ ]+\\s+")))
```

-output

```
 ID                         Tweet        Original_Tweet        Reply_tweet
1  1 @mcr_chick i wanna sleep.lol.                  <NA> i wanna sleep.lol.
2  2         Someone burned a hole Someone burned a hole               <NA>
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:2, Tweet = c("@mcr_chick i wanna sleep.lol.", 
"Someone burned a hole")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Answer (score 3):

Slightly different method from akrun's

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- tibble(id=c(1,2),
       tweet=c("@mcr_chick i wanna sleep.lol.",
               "Someone burned a hole."))

data %>%
  mutate(
    #original tweet
    original = ifelse(
        #look for twitter handle
      str_detect(tweet, "@\\w+"), 
        # if found, NA
      NA,
        # otherwise, text in tweet column
      tweet),
    #reply tweet
    reply = ifelse(
        # look for twitter handle
      str_detect(tweet, "@\\w+"),
        # if found, remove handle
        str_remove(tweet,"@\\w+"),
        # otherwise NA
        NA),
    #clean up some whitespace
    reply = str_trim(reply)
    )
```

This returns:

```
id    tweet               original         reply       
<dbl> <chr>               <chr>            <chr>       
1      @mcr_chick i wanna~ NA               i wanna sle~
2      Someone burned a h~ Someone burned ~ NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative way using a defined regex pattern `" ?@\\w+ ?"` that basically searches for all strings that start with `@` until the end of that string:

Then we use some `stringr` functions combined with an `ifelse` statement:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
tweet_pattern <- " ?@\\w+ ?"

df %>% 
    mutate(Original_Tweet = str_replace(Tweet, tweet_pattern, NA_character_),
           Reply_Tweet = ifelse(str_detect(Tweet, tweet_pattern), 
                                str_remove(Tweet, tweet_pattern), 
                                NA_character_))
```

Output:

```
  ID                         Tweet         Original_Tweet        Reply_Tweet
1  1 @mcr_chick i wanna sleep.lol.                   <NA> i wanna sleep.lol.
2  2        Someone burned a hole. Someone burned a hole.               <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic is similar to @Anthony Schmidt's answer here but in base R.

```
transform(data, Original_Tweet = ifelse(grepl('@',tweet,fixed = TRUE),NA, tweet),
          reply_tweet = ifelse(grepl('@', tweet, fixed = TRUE), 
                        sub('@.*?\\s+', '', tweet), NA))

#  id                         tweet         Original_Tweet        reply_tweet
#1  1 @mcr_chick i wanna sleep.lol.                   <NA> i wanna sleep.lol.
#2  2        Someone burned a hole. Someone burned a hole.               <NA>
```